How to dismantle a RST 381L fork?
I have an old 1996 RST 381L fork and can’t get the elastomer rods to come out. I have tried break cleaner and gasoline but they don’t really move. I have replacement elastomers that I am trying to get out on. Any ideas?

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Does the answer on this question help at all?

Rule #1 using gasoline to clean anything is a bad idea

Welcome to the site - this is such a good question, its already been asked before and has been answered.   This one will be closed as a duplicate.

The previous answer did not solve the issue. This was looking for other ideas.
